# Excel circular reference in formula

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010

I'm having a problem with formulas in excel.

The formula of `E4` is:

> =IF(D4<>0;D4;E6+E5)

The formula of `E5` is:

> =IF(E4<>0;E4*C5;E6/F6*C5)

What I want to do is calculate the cells **in both directions.**

`D4` is a fix value that can be 0.
`E4` is eather `D4` (if it's given) or calculated by `E6+E5` (then it's the value to be calculated)

`E5` should be `E4*C5` if `E4` is given, else it's calculated via `E6/F6*C5`.

How can I resolve this circular reference error?

[image: Circular Reference]

Comment: What's the meaning of In and Out? I get the gross, discount and net bit

Comment: Not possible calculation in both directions using the same cells. Either use different cells (sheet parts) for forward and backward calculation or calculate forward only and use goal seek for backwards.

Comment: @RobinMackenzie In means that its possible to set a value (-> Input) and Out are the calculations